# JLabel strech to end of container

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, grouplayout

I'm trying to insert a `JLabel` into a `JTabbedPane` and have it stretch from the left to the right ends. I can insert it and manipulate the width manually, but don't know how to do it automatically. Below is what it looks like now. The white border should ideally stretch to the right side.
[image]

I'm using a `GroupLayout` for this and I am very unfamiliar with it so that's why I'm asking. Below is the code for the page.

```
public class Gen1 extends JPanel {
    private MaterialTabbed tabs;
    private JPanel red, blue, yellow;
    
    public Gen1() {
        initComponents();
        setOpaque(false);
        initRed();
    }
    
    private void initRed() {
        JLabel gcea = new JLabel();
        gcea.setText("Gotta Catch 'Em All");
        gcea.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 5));
        gcea.setBackground(new Color(251, 188, 4));
        
        GroupLayout redLayout = new GroupLayout(red);
            red.setLayout(redLayout);
            redLayout.setHorizontalGroup(redLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(redLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(gcea, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, tabs.getUI().getTabBounds(tabs, 0).width, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap(518, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            redLayout.setVerticalGroup(redLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(redLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(gcea)
                    .addContainerGap(256, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        tabs = new MaterialTabbed();
        red = new ChecklistPage(new BorderLayout());
        blue = new ChecklistPage(new BorderLayout());
        yellow = new ChecklistPage(new BorderLayout());
        
        tabs.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.RIGHT);
                
        GroupLayout redLayout = new GroupLayout(red);
        red.setLayout(redLayout);
        redLayout.setHorizontalGroup(redLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 655, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        redLayout.setVerticalGroup(redLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 332, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        tabs.addTab("", ImageResize.resize(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/gamecovers/red.png")), 100), red);

        GroupLayout blueLayout = new GroupLayout(blue);
        blue.setLayout(blueLayout);
        blueLayout.setHorizontalGroup(blueLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 655, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        blueLayout.setVerticalGroup(blueLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 332, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        tabs.addTab("", ImageResize.resize(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/gamecovers/blue.png")), 100), blue);
        
        GroupLayout yellowLayout = new GroupLayout(yellow);
        yellow.setLayout(yellowLayout);
        yellowLayout.setHorizontalGroup(yellowLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 655, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        yellowLayout.setVerticalGroup(yellowLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 332, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        tabs.addTab("", ImageResize.resize(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/gamecovers/yellow.png")), 100), yellow);
        
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(tabs, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 500, Short.MAX_VALUE).addContainerGap()));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(tabs, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 288, Short.MAX_VALUE).addContainerGap()));
    }
}
```

`MaterialTabbed` is just a custom `JTabbedPane` and `ChecklistPage` is a custom `JPanel`. Also the `setBackground` method isn't working either, if anyone has a fix for that as well.

Comment: Don't know about GroupLayout, but to get the label background color use `gcea.setOpaque(true)` in addition to `gcea.setBackground(...)`.

Comment: GroupLayout is one of the hardest layouts to work with.  If all of the components in the lighter gray area are going to be the same size, use GridLayout.  If not, you may be able to use a vertical BoxLayout.  If neither of those is sufficient, GridBagLayout is quite versatile, but its versatility means it’s harder to learn.

Comment: I would use a `BorderLayout` and add the label to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`. The height will be respected and the width will fill the panel. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.